# How to change jar packaging into pom packaging in Java project

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml

I have a single Java Maven project having a `pom.xml` with `jar` packaging.
Now I want to add a sub-project in that project. So, I need to change the packaging `pom` from `jar`.

```
<groupId>org.test.app</groupId>
<artifactId>testPom</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

Please provide any suggestion.

Comment: <packaging>pom</packaging> how else?

Comment: Are you aware of that nothing will be processed in `src/[main|test]/...` once you change the packaging type to `pom`, i.e. no `<project>.jar` will be created?

Answer (score 4):

This would be the parent POM part with packaging and a couple of module references:

```
<groupId>org.test.app</groupId>
<artifactId>testPom</artifactId>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<modules>
    <module>submodule</module>
    <module>another-submodule</module>
</modules>
```

Hope it helps.